# AVAudioPCMBuffer Memory Management

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioengine, avaudiopcmbuffer

I’m using `AVAudioEngine` to get a stream of `AVAudioPCMBuffers` from the device’s microphone using the usual `installTap(onBus:)` setup.

To distribute the audio stream to other parts of the program, I’m sending the buffers to a Combine publisher similar to the following:

```swift
private let publisher = PassthroughSubject<AVAudioPCMBuffer, Never>()
```

I’m starting to suspect I have some kind of concurrency or memory management issue with the buffers, because when consuming the buffers elsewhere I’m getting a range of crashes that suggest some internal pointer in a buffer is NULL (specifically, I’m seeing crashes in `vDSP.convertElements(of:to:)` when I try to read samples from the buffer using, say, `floatChannelData`).

These crashes are in production and fairly rare — I can’t reproduce them locally.

I never modify the audio buffers, only read them for analysis.

---

My question is: should it be possible to put `AVAudioPCMBuffers` into a Combine pipeline? Does the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` class not retain/release the underlying `AudioBufferList`’s memory the way I’m assuming? Is this a fundamentally flawed approach?

Comment: `AVAudioPCMBuffer` does retain its own data, but `floatChannelData` does not - are you definitely retaining the buffer while accessing the audio data?

Comment: Yeah, the buffers should be retained by the Combine publisher? I’m subscribing as follows: `audioEngine.packets.sink(receiveValue: audioLevelCalculator.add(packet:)).store(in: &subscriptions)`. (The level calculator method just reads a few sample values from the buffer and never touches it again). (To be clear, `audioEngine` there is my own class that provides the buffers under a `packets` publisher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rule inside audio callback functions, blocks, or taps to always immediately copy any data to be processed out of the PCM buffers into your own private sample buffers.  You can then safely publish your copy, and/or process the copied data at you own convenience.

This is because the underlying PCM buffers might be being updated in a separate RemoteIO Audio Unit thread running inside a hard real-time (Mach kernel) context.  And thus its possible that some audio unit implementations might potentially be ignoring all concurrency locks in order to attempt to meet their hard real-time completion targets.